# Register a custom camera source with the Camera API

Tags: android

I have quite a bit of experience with the camera API, but I could not find any documentation to answer this question...

Most phones already have a front and a back camera. Would it be possible to simulate a 3rd camera via software (probably using a service), and register that with the api?

The idea would be that we define a custom camera, register it with the Api, and then any camera app would be able to get it by looping through the available cameras.

I imagine several cases where we might want this...

1. There are some external cameras (such as the FLIR thermal camera) that could provide this.
2. We might want to concatenate the front and back camera images into a single image, and preview that. I know not all phones support opening both cameras concurrently, but some do, and i could imagine this functionality would be cool for 3rd party video chat apps like Skype... Specifically, since Skype doesnt natively support this, by registering directly with the Android Camera Api, we could get around the limitations of the Skype API, since our custom camera would just look like one of the default Android cameras.

So would this be possible? Or what is the technical limitations that prevents us from doing it. Perhaps the Android Api simply doesnt let us define a custom source (I know the Sensor API doesnt, so I would not be surprised if this was the case for the Camera API as well).